# Many int values in filter SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I try to filter data by a few numbers, cant use IN because it requires string value. How can I do this?

I tried sth like this but it doesn't work. How can I pas A FEW int values to filter?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a parameter (filter) in your report that will accept numbers separated by `,` or some other character. That parameter will be string and it will look like this:

[image]

In SQL procedure separate those values using `SPLIT_STRING` function.

Here's a simple example.

`CREATE TABLE #Numbers ( Num INT )
INSERT INTO #Numbers (Num) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #Numbers (Num) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO #Numbers (Num) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO #Numbers (Num) VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO #Numbers (Num) VALUES(5)`

Task is to select some values from `#Numbers` table. Values to be selected are:

`DECLARE @MyValues CHAR(100) = '1, 3, 5, 7'`

In your example `@MyValues` is report parameter.

Those values will be separated by:

`DECLARE @Separator CHAR = ','`

Next step is to separate `@MyValues` and store them:

`CREATE TABLE #SplitValues ( NumValues INT )
INSERT INTO #SplitValues
SELECT TRIM(Value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@MyValues, @Separator)`

Last step is to select `@MyValues` from `#Numbers` table:

`SELECT * FROM #Numbers
WHERE
    Num IN (SELECT * FROM #SplitValues)`

Instead of using `#SplitValues` table there is an option of using `SELECT TRIM(Value) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@MyValues, @Separator)` directly in the last `select`, however, that way functions `TRIM` and `SPLIT_STRING` are called for every row in `#Numbers` table, which is "heavier" to execute.

Finally, instead of a string parameter, you can create a drop-down checkbox list and pass its values the same way, as a string that contains numbers separated by coma.

Comment: Thanks. However I found other solution. I typed =New Integer{30,35} in filter and it worked:)